# div pushing another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I see similar problems but different to mine. I am working on a website where the upper half of the height is fixed. The main section where all the content is below the fixed header. My fixed menu keeps pushing the content down when called when they don't even overlap. My code...simplified.

```
<header>
 <div class ="content">
     <--- content here ->
 </div>
 <div class="menu">
  <----fixed menu content here --->
 </div>
 <---- js to display fixed menu --->
</header>

<main>
  <section> content here </section>
  <section> content here </section>
  <section> content here </section>
<main>
```

My CSS:

```
 header {position:fixed; top 0; height:50vh; }
 menu {position: fixed; top:0; height: 0; width: 100%; }
 main {margin-top:50vh; }
```

My JS:

```
<script>
    function openNav() {
     document.getElementById("menu").style.height = "50vh";
    }

    function closeNav() {
     document.getElementById("menu").style.height = "0";
    }
</script>
```

When you enable the fixed-menu, the menu replaces the entire header. That's my what I want. that part works. When your looking at the first section content. It works, also. But any content below the first section when enabling the menu just pushes the content all the way back to the first section. Any help is appreciated. If there is a better way to do this I'm also open to suggestions.

Comment: any way you could wire up an example snippet with what you started above? It would be much easier to answer

Comment: @Kinglish , that is literally the structure of my html and a simplified css of the original.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was my link to toggle the fixed menu. Because it was a link and not a button, it would scroll all the way to the link.